# How to get pandas to add a count column based on a group in one column and value within that group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set consisting of an ID and a description of pictures associated with that ID.  I would like to add a column that counts the pictures based on the description for each id.  For example, if id '001' has 4 pictures of garages, I want a column that counts 1,2,3,4 until the ID switches.  See example below:

```
   description   id
0       garage  001
1       garage  001
2       garage  002
3       garage  003
4         side  001
5         side  002
6         side  002
7         side  003
8        front  003
9        front  001
10       front  001
```

Expected result:

```
   description   id  count
0       garage  001      1
1       garage  001      2
2       garage  002      1
3       garage  003      1
4         side  001      1
5         side  002      1
6         side  002      2
7         side  003      1
8        front  003      1
9        front  001      1
10       front  001      2
```

I will use this later to pivot out each description in columns. I can't pivot them out with out adding a counter and concatenating them.

Comment: @ALollz I got all `1`'s.

Comment: @QuangHoang: ALollz's solution works. You got all `1` because your df already created columns `count` from your solution.

Comment: @AndyL. aha, silly me.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry that's a lazy (and error-prone) way to specify the grouping columns. Better to specify the actual columns: `.groupby(['description', 'id'])`